# Can I route individual websites to a multi-site Drupal installation?

Tags: multi-sites

This isn't really Drupal-specific, but perhaps someone is already doing this with Drupal and can guide me. I host a few sites for my customers and several of those are Drupal-based, using a multi-site installation. No problems, except that those are not individual cPanel accounts, of course, and the customer cannot manage any part of their account -- I have to do it all.

Is it possible to set up my Drupal customers with individual cPanel accounts, yet route all their web traffic to the multi-site Drupal installation on my reseller account (typical reseller account on a shared host)?

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this done in cpanel. Maybe under your reseller account 
you could  create a instance of multi-site and then create sub-domains then
your clients could domain could be redirected to the subdomain?

Have you tried talking to the guys who created cpanel that might
be another resource

http://forums.cpanel.net/forum.php

Comment: The redirect won't be acceptable to my customers. I'm thinking that instead I need to put a DNS entry (A record, through WHM) to route the traffic to the reseller server -- but that server needs to know to expect that domain's traffic. So far, though, I've been unable to create that domain there because the server is aware it exists as a separate account. I'll check with the cPanel folks, though.